# How do store pdf to sdcard on Android in Rhomobile

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I have to store a pdf that i'm generating through my application. I don't know the path for the sdcard for storing the file.

I guess the path needs to go into here

```
pdf.save_as(file_location)
```

Can anyone suggest the path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `/sdcard/` to store files on to the sdcard for Android

```
file_location = File.join('/sdcard/','My.pdf')
pdf.save_as(file_location)
```